# What is the Character Encoding of x509 certificates?

Tags: certificate, java, x509, encoding, scep

I'm implementing an SCEP server to distribute client certificates. According to the [protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-gutmann-scep/?include_text=1), For the `GetCACert` request from device, the content-type of the response header should be `application/x-x509-ca-cert`.

My problem is that by default, the character encoding of every response is set as `UTF-8` by my application's filter and so the response becomes `application/x-x509-ca-cert;charset=UTF-8`. The device doesn't like this character encoding part and rejects the response.

I suspected that the device might try to convert the response from UTF-8 format,and so I tried to encode my response to UTF-8, but the device still doesn't accept my response.

I then set burp proxy to device and removed the `charset=UTF-8` part from response header and the device accepted the response.

Upon some googling, I found that the certificates are encoded with `DER`, but when I gave `DER` as the character encoding, java says `unknown-encoding` and also the [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) character encoding doesn't have `DER` in their official charsets.

My question is "what is the official charset name that can be used to define the character encoding of x509 certificate?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificates are binary. They have no character encoding since these are no characters but plain octets (bytes). It will not help if you try to encode these non-characters with some character encoding. Instead you need to omit the charset attribute.